# Track Start and end web request at ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using ionic framework and Angular JS.

I am not sure where to start to track start of a web request.

For end request, I write a directive with onLoad tag.

here is the code

**Directive.js**

```
app.directive('iframeOnload', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            callBack: '&iframeOnload'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('load', function(){
                return scope.callBack({DOMelement: this});
            })
        }
    }}]);
```

At the **HTML**

```
<iframe id="webFrame" iframe-onload="iframeLoadedCallBack()" style="width:100%;height:650px;" ng-src='{{goToURL}}' ng-hide='hideIFrame'></iframe>
```

At the **Controller**
The callback function is

```
    $scope.iframeLoadedCallBack = function() {
        console.log('iframeLoadedCallback');
        // finished web request callback do something here
    };
```

I guess there is something similar for start of the web request. And I need to track the send request URL.

I am an iOS developer, And actually I would like to do something similar to this protocol
[UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Thanks a lot

Comment: turned out that interceptors from $httpProvider don't catch requests of iframe, my bad, sorry.

Comment: The interceptors catch all the request of $http object include the ui-route. I hope it helps someone using alternative method for loading the external link.

Comment: it also catches all requests for template html, that's why I thought it should help with iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may not work perfectly, at the iframeLoadedCallback

you could add the following code

```
 var webFrame = angular.element(document.getElementById('webFrame'));
 webFrame[0].contentDocument.onclick = $scope.clickOnIframe;
```

and it will track every click event inside the iframe, rest of it would be hard code to track by ID, tag, class etc inside the event.

I hope it helps someone has similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can track all web requests using NSURLProtocol hope this may help.